# PointStamped from tf2_ros::Buffer

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently attempting to complete the following [TF tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF), however using TF2 instead of TF.

The part I'm struggling with is transforming the PointStamped. In standard TF the following would suffice

```
listener.transformPoint("base_link", laser_point, base_point);
```

However, from TF2 (as far as I am aware) `transformPoint` no longer exists and has been replaced by `transform` from the `tf2_ros::Buffer` library.

The final resulting function looks like so:

```
//void transformPoint(const tf::TransformListener& listener){ - TF version
    void transformPoint(const tf2_ros::Buffer& tfBuffer){
            geometry_msgs::PointStamped laser_point;
        
            laser_point.header.frame_id = "base_laser";
        
            laser_point.header.stamp = ros::Time();
        
            laser_point.point.x = 1.0;
            laser_point.point.y = 0.2;
            laser_point.point.z = 0.0;
        
            try{
                geometry_msgs::PointStamped base_point;
                
                //listener.transformPoint("base_link", laser_point, base_point); - TF version
                base_point = tfBuffer.transform(laser_point, "base_link");
        
                ROS_INFO("base_laser: (%.2f, %.2f. %.2f) -> base_link: (%.2f, %.2f, %.2f) at time %.2f",
                        laser_point.point.x, laser_point.point.y, laser_point.point.z,
                        base_point.point.x, base_point.point.y, base_point.point.z, 
                        base_point.header.stamp.toSec());
        
            }catch(tf2::TransformException& ex){
                 ROS_ERROR("Received ... from \"base_laser\" to \"base_link\": %s", ex.what());
            }
     }
```

Whilst the above code appears to pass the build stages, I receive a compile error which I'm struggling to dissect (apologies for posting such a large error message):

```
  CMakeFiles/tf2_listener.dir/src/tf2_listener.cpp.o: In function `geometry_msgs::PointStamped_<std::allocator<void> >& tf2_ros::BufferInterface::transform<geometry_msgs::PointStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >(geometry_msgs::PointStamped_<std::allocator<void> > const&, geometry_msgs::PointStamped_<std::allocator<void> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, ros::Duration) const':
tf2_listener.cpp:(.text._ZNK7tf2_ros15BufferInterface9transformIN13geometry_msgs13PointStamped_ISaIvEEEEERT_RKS6_S7_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEN3ros8DurationE[_ZNK7tf2_ros15BufferInterface9transformIN13geometry_msgs13PointStamped_ISaIvEEEEERT_RKS6_S7_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEN3ros8DurationE]+0x69): undefined reference to `ros::Time const& tf2::getTimestamp<geometry_msgs::PointStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >(geometry_msgs::PointStamped_<std::allocator<void> > const&)'
tf2_listener.cpp:(.text._ZNK7tf2_ros15BufferInterface9transformIN13geometry_msgs13PointStamped_ISaIvEEEEERT_RKS6_S7_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEN3ros8DurationE[_ZNK7tf2_ros15BufferInterface9transformIN13geometry_msgs13PointStamped_ISaIvEEEEERT_RKS6_S7_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEN3ros8DurationE]+0x7b): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const& tf2::getFrameId<geometry_msgs::PointStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >(geometry_msgs::PointStamped_<std::allocator<void> > const&)'
tf2_listener.cpp:(.text._ZNK7tf2_ros15BufferInterface9transformIN13geometry_msgs13PointStamped_ISaIvEEEEERT_RKS6_S7_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEN3ros8DurationE[_ZNK7tf2_ros15BufferInterface9transformIN13geometry_msgs13PointStamped_ISaIvEEEEERT_RKS6_S7_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEN3ros8DurationE]+0xc8): undefined reference to `void tf2::doTransform<geometry_msgs::PointStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >(geometry_msgs::PointStamped_<std::allocator<void> > const&, geometry_msgs::PointStamped_<std::allocator<void> >&, geometry_msgs::TransformStamped_<std::allocator<void> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
robot_setup_tf2/CMakeFiles/tf2_listener.dir/build.make:118: recipe for target '/home/connor/catkin_ws/devel/lib/robot_setup_tf2/tf2_listener' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/connor/catkin_ws/devel/lib/robot_setup_tf2/tf2_listener] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1469: recipe for target 'robot_setup_tf2/CMakeFiles/tf2_listener.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [robot_setup_tf2/CMakeFiles/tf2_listener.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j24 -l24" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349884/pointstamped-from-tf2_ros::buffer/) by [connor.p](https://answers.ros.org/users/53472/connor.p/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

-- Answering my own question --

Whilst reviewing my error message I noticed the following extract:

```
undefined reference to void tf2::doTransform ...
```

Following some research I concluded that I need to include the `tf2_geometry_msgs` library to allow for [converting between various geometry_msgs data types](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/tf2_geometry_msgs/html/c++/index.html).

Added code:

```
#include "tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h"
```

With this library now included the problem as been resolved.

---

Originally posted by [connor.p](https://answers.ros.org/users/53472/connor.p/) with karma: 16 on 2020-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0